# Makefile which can generate all object files in a specific path

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Somewhere I am going wrong !!

I am trying to generate the object files in **../bin/**

But the below code generates in corresponding source file directory.

Below the code, which I am running.

### Modified code:

```
LIB = $(BIN_DIR)/libutils.a
APP = $(BIN_DIR)/app

CC = gcc
AR = ar

CFLAGS = -Wall -g
LDFLAGS =


all: $(LIB) $(APP)

SRC =   $(SRC_DIR)/add.c \
        $(SRC_DIR)/sub.c 

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)


INCLUDES = -I$(INC_DIR)/
LIBS = -L../ -L/usr/local/lib -lm

LDFLAGS = -g
.SUFFIXES: .c

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $(SRC_DIR)/$< -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@

$(LIB): $(OBJ)
$(AR) rcs $(LIB) $(OBJ)

$(BIN_DIR)/app: $(BIN_DIR)/test.o \
                $(BIN_DIR)/t.o \
                $(BIN_DIR)/libutils.a
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
    
clean:
    rm -f $(LIB) $(BIN_DIR)/* $(SRC_DIR)/*.o *.o
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have the rule:

```
$(LIB): $(OBJ)
    ...
```

and `OBJ` is still `src_dir/add.o src_dir/sub.o`, so that's where Make will try to build these objects *if your object rule works as intended*. So, first step:

SRC =   $(SRC_DIR)/add.c \
        $(SRC_DIR)/sub.c

<strike>OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)</strike>
OBJ = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c,$(BIN_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC))

Now you'll find that your object rule,

```
.c.o:
    ...
```

doesn't work, because it expects to find the source file in the same place where the object file should go (i.e. `$(OBJ_DIR)`). So replace this rule with:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
```

I notice that you have no provision for building `$(BIN_DIR)/t.o` and `$(BIN_DIR)/test.o`, but the app needs them. You should look into that.

Further refinements are possible, but this is a start.

Comment: I appreciate your write up. it works fine for me !!
Upvoted :)

I would like to move further @Beta.
Say I have two different source directories: one is src/ and the other  is test/ under same path.

Comment: now I am able to generate all the obj files from src/ under bin/ and generating lib.a file under bin/ ..
Same way, how can I generate object file from test/*.c files under bin/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Your SRC has a relative path, and your OBJ is just the SRC with the extension changed to. o

So OBJ will contain this:

```
../src/add.o
../src/sub.o
```

And there is where the .o will be created.

Make these changes and it will work:

```
SRC =   add.c \
        sub.c

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c ../src/$< -o ../bin/$@
```

Comment: You are welcome. I just updated my answer to provide a solution

Comment: sorry,
it could not resolve, creating the object files in ../bin/src directory.
Rather it creates in ../src/

Comment: Did you change the SRC variable as suggested? Removing the path altogether? Can you modify your code to reflect it?

Comment: If this solved your issue, do him the favor of accepting his answer.  If you still have trouble, let us know what it is.

Comment: I am sorry.. could not fix.

All the object files are generated in $(SRC_DIR)/    


hence it results the error as $(BIN_DIR)/test.o is needed by $(BIN_DIR)/app

Comment: This is not the right answer.  Beta's answer is correct.  You cannot put object files in directories other than source files using the old-style suffix rules.  You _must_ use pattern rules.  Even though DWilches answer seems to work at this level, you're lying to make: if you try to create a rule that depends on these object files everything will break down, because your makefile says the rule builds `foo.o` but the rule _actually_ builds `../bin/foo.o`.  That will cause you heartburn.

Comment: Thank you @MadScientist

Added comment to Beta.. Please get time to look into it.
Thanking you with anticipation :)